# How do I segue within imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: to dismiss imagePickerController

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am smitten by `UIStoryboard` and now of course want to use them everywhere. I have presented a `imagePickerController` via a push seque. Fine.

Now, from the delegate method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` I want to dismiss the `imagePickerController` using a segue rather then `[imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`.

Is this even possible? I tried wiring up the segue in IB but could not figure up how to assign a name to the segue to use in my code.

Thanks in advance,
Doug

Comment: What about, if the delegate is in the ViewController that has the segue, doing `[imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:XxX]`, and performing the segue in the completion?

Comment: Lame, as I understand it - and as I use them - segue replaces present/dismiss VC.